# What is the analogue of a dielectric in magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, magnetic-fields

Capacitors and dielectrics pertain electric phenomena, one could say that inductors can be considered analogues of capacitors in the magnetic case.

Is there a dielectric analogue in magnetism?
What about dielectric relaxation in electricity, is there any such thing as magnetic relaxation? Can it be magnetic hysteresis?

Comment: Related: [Magnetic Susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_susceptibility) on Wikipedia. And, for comparison: [Electric Susceptibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_susceptibility). Sadly it's beyond me to summarize these in a way that would answer your question succinctly.

Comment: Yes. It's called a paramagnet.